# Swift: CustomStringConvertible array of array, any other way?

Tags: arrays, swift

I have an `Array<Array<Character>>`,

I want to print it like this, line by line:

```
["E", "E", "E", "E", "E"]
["E", "E", "M", "E", "E"]
["E", "E", "E", "E", "E"]
["B", "E", "E", "E", "E"]
```

Here is my way:

```
extension Array where Element == Array<Character>{
    func debug(){
        for element in self{
            print(element)
        }
    }
}

array.debug()
```

**Any Other better way?**

when using `CustomStringConvertible` like below,

```
extension Array: CustomStringConvertible where Element == Array<Character>{
       var description: String{
             ""
             // ...
       }
}
```

Xcode tips:

> Conformance of 'Array' to protocol 'CustomStringConvertible'
> conflicts with that stated in the type's module 'Swift' and will be
> ignored; there cannot be more than one conformance, even with
> different conditional bounds

Comment: Do you want the `[`, `"`, `,`, to be printed as well?

Comment: Not need. Line by line is OK

Comment: Why do you think your current way is bad? In other words, what do you mean by a "better way"?

Comment: Are you just trying to print every element of the Array?

Comment: I am a new programmer, may be there is @ Sweeper

Comment: yes, just that simple @PGDev

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're simply trying to print every `element` of the `Array`, you don't need to create any extra `extension` for that.

Simply run a **`forEach(_:)`** loop on it, i.e.

```
arr.forEach({ print($0) })
```